# Intel USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller Installation Fails

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, bsod

The problem I have is getting my HP DV7T-7000 Windows 7 64-bit laptop's USB 3.0 ports to function at USB 3.0 speeds.  I used to get 3.0 speeds but noticed I'm having a problem in the last few months.  When I attach a USB 3.0 device to a USB 3.0 port I get the message that says your device can perform faster when attached to a super speed port.

I've tried to uninstall the Intel USB 3.0 extensible host controller driver.  Re-installation of the latest driver from Intel failed and I got a BSOD during the installation.  I updated my BIOS with the latest firmware from HP and the BSOD ceased but the driver still wouldn't install properly.  I get an installation error and after restarting the USB 3.0 controller is installed but not USB 3.0 Hub which shows to be an Unknown Device.  The driver installation log reveals the details below.

When I tried the Controller driver supplied by HP for my laptop I get a prompt saying that the "PCI Bus" driver that's installed on my system is newer than the one that's getting installed and whether I want to overwrite it.  I don't have System Restore activated on my system and I also don't want to go through the tedious process of re-installing Windows and setup my development environment again.  It's worth mentioning that I use Advance System Optimizer to keep my drivers up to date.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**IntelUSB3.log:**

```
[File - 400]
  Operation = copy
  Destination = C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller Driver\Drivers\IUsb3Hub.man
    Copying file C:\Users\user\Downloads\Intel(R)_USB_3.0_eXtensible_Host_Controller_Driver\drivers\Win7\x64\IUsb3Hub.man
[INF - 500]
  Installing C:\Users\user\Downloads\Intel(R)_USB_3.0_eXtensible_Host_Controller_Driver\Drivers\Win7\x64\iusb3hub.inf
  INF = C:\Users\user\Downloads\Intel(R)_USB_3.0_eXtensible_Host_Controller_Driver\Drivers\Win7\x64\iusb3hub.inf
  Execute command: C:\Users\user\Downloads\Intel(R)_USB_3.0_eXtensible_Host_Controller_Driver\x64\Drv64.exe -driverinf "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Intel(R)_USB_3.0_eXtensible_Host_Controller_Driver\Drivers\Win7\x64\iusb3hub.inf" -flags 20 -keypath "Software\Intel\Difx64"
!   DriverPackageInstall error 0x3EE
IIF will NOT initiate reboot
Exit code = 0x3EE
ResultCode = 1006
```

Comment: Its unlikely a fresh installation would solve this problem.  In order to explain the reason for that.  I need to know how many USB devices you have connected to your computer.

Comment: When installing the drivers I made sure no devices were attached. Typically I would attach 1 or 2 external USB 3.0 hard-drives but I don't see how this question is relevant.  Please explain.

Comment: All questions I ask within a comment is relevant.  **I had my reasons.**

Comment: Please upload the file **C:\Windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log**

Comment: As requested, here you go sir: [link](http://dropcanvas.com/b2qgn)

Comment: you use an old Version ofthe USB driver (1.0.0.199), try the latest one: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=3467&DwnldID=21129&keyword=USB+3.0&lang=eng

Comment: does the newer driver works or not?

Comment: @Ramhound , hi could you explain the connection between the issue and the number of usb devices connected? thanks. m

Comment: I had a similar problem on a dell computer. I solved it by removing previously installed two devices: "Unknown Device" and usb 3.0 extensible device in device manager. Then I restarted windows. Then in device manager I manually installed driver for device which had a missing driver with iusb3xhc driver files. I needed to put them in a separate folder because originally they were together with iusb3hub driver files which was causing incorrect installation of both at same time. After installing iusb3xhc driver I did restart. After restart I installed iusb3hub driver. Again restart and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update that PCI bus driver.  That's the driver for the USB3<->PCIe bridge controller, and if it says the one already installed is newer, then it's likely a mismatched version to the XHCI and root hub drivers.

Your best bet is to download the newest driver straight from Intel.  There are two of them and you probably tried the wrong one.  Based on the log file you posted, [This is the driver you need](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=3467&DwnldID=21129&ProductFamily=Software+Products&ProductLine=Chipset+Software&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+USB+3.0+eXtensible+Host+Controller+Driver&lang=eng)

Also, do not allow your 3rd party driver update software to update that bridge driver.  The PCI ID is the same as Intel's USB2 bridge chip, but the driver file is different.  If that software detects that there's a newer version, it might replace it with the wrong file again.  In fact, that may be why it broke in the first place.

Comment: Wes, I followed the link you gave me and I definitely tried installing the C216 driver and not the C220.  Details of the "PCI Bus" driver that's installed are provider AMD, version 13.15.1.1, date 2013/07/24.  From what I can see this is the latest version available so it would mean that I have to downgrade this driver, right?  What do you suggest I do?